# Part of the link is hidden

Tags: html, apache

I can see numerous websites that have a part of their link hidden. For example, twitter.com has no index.php / index html / index.asp whatsoever. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely an Apache rule.

Read up on Apache and .htaccess files to learn more about them: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

Because they have defined this page as a default document in their respective web servers meaning that if it is not specified the web server automatically picks it. The way to achieve this varies between the different platforms and web servers. It could also be done on the application level. For example in ASP.NET MVC you could define in your route definition the default controller and action to be served:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

This way if the user requests `/` the Index action on the HomeController will be executed.